# Every ring with unity has a subring isomorphic to either $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Every ring with unity has a subring isomorphic to either $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_n$. I know that is true but I am looking for a reference to a book with a proof. From [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/709105) I know such book exists.

Comment: Look at the unique $f:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow R$ homomorphism satisfying $f(1)=1$ at examine the image of $\mathbb{Z}$

Comment: Just add/subtract 1 to itself as many times as possible.

Comment: That subring is called the prime ring of the original ring.

Answer (score 1):

The book might be [Algebra by Serge Lang](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4613-0041-0), which says the following:

Let $A$ be a ring, and denote its unit element by $e$ for the moment. The
map
$$\lambda:\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow A$$
such that $\lambda(n)=ne$ is a ring-homomorphism (obvious), and its kernel is an ideal $(n)$, generated by an integer $n > 0$. We have a canonical injective homo­morphism $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z\to A$, which is a (ring) isomorphism between $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ and a subring of $A$.

If $n\mathbb Z$ is a prime ideal, then $n = 0$ or $n = p$ for some prime number $p$. In the first case, $A$ contains as a subring a ring which is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$, and which is often identified with $\mathbb Z$. In that case, we say that $A$ has characteristic $0$. If on the other hand $n = p$, then we say that $A$ has characteristic $p$, and $A$ contains (an isomorphic image of) $\mathbb Z/p\mathbb Z$ as a subring.